# Почему IDE не показывает подсказки по методам класса?

Tags: php, ide, netbeans

Создал класс A, B и C в 1 папке. В классе A есть переменная `public $b`, которая в `__construct` равняется `new B()`. В классе B есть публичный метод render. Класс C наследуется от A и имеет публичный метод `some();` В методе some я хочу вызвать метод экземпляра класса B, но не получаю подсказку о его наличии, хотя срабатывает он отлично

```
class A {
    public $b;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B();
    }
}
class B {
    public function render() {
    }
}
class C extends A {
    public function b()
    {
        $this->b->render();
    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос почему мне IDE не подсказывает про методы класса B и как это реализовать?
Все классы в разных файлах.

Comment: какая  IDE???? серьёзно?

Comment: @n.osennij NetBeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменил `public $b` на `protected $b` и все заработало. Хотя на самом деле проблема была в том, что `netbeans` такие вещи не мог видеть без `doc block`... Очень странно.

Comment: всё верно, нужно документировать. Или на какую подсказку вы рассчитывали ?